# How to serve ZipOutputStream to network in JAVA

Tags: java, zipinputstream

I am writing a server in `JAVA`, where client requests to download multiple files and server will create a `ZipOutputStream` and serve immediately. On the other hand another thread will write to `ZipOutputStream`. I used `piped input/output stream`.

## Code

```
PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();
PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream();
in.connect(out);
ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(out);
new Thread{
  public void run(){
       while(condition){
           more logic.. 
           zout.write(data,0,length);
           zout.flush()
       }
       zout.close();
       out.close();
  }
}.start();
return in;
```

But when I click download button it download(finish immediately) a small file(corrupted) while my zip creating job is still running. How can I synchronize these two job?

Comment: Vaiya, did you flush after write?

Comment: I didn't but flush doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you closing the PipedOutputstream before the Thread writing to zout finished?

Comment: No, it close after zout.

Comment: I have solved it. Sorry but problem was not in zip code, I had to add checked(true) header in response.

Comment: Why the threads? There are few essential uses of `PipedOutputStream` and friends, and this doesn't appear to be one of them. Just wrap the `ZipOutputStream` around the response output stream and do it all in the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should `flush` and then close `ZipOutputStream`. And better use `ZipEntry` to create archive

```
    ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(out);
    new Thread {
        public void run () {
            while (condition) {
                // logic ...
                zipEntry = new ZipEntry("name");
                zout.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                zout.write(data);
                zout.flush();
                zout.closeEntry();
            }
            zout.flush();
            zout.close();
        }
    }.start();

    return in;
```

Comment: I exactly did the same code. I didn't use flush and closeEntry methods first time. But using those methods also didn't help.